# useEffect alternate for Class Component

Tags: reactjs

I just learned that in functional components I can use `useEffect` to keep an eye on any side effect (ex: when using `localStorage`) which makes sure my state is hooked up with the effect.

I want to have similar functionality in my class based Component for `localStorage`. How can I make sure that my state updates itself as soon as there is any change into the `localStorage`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please Show us

Comment: u want to use  lifecycle methods here a link https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I did it.

```
class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            // Get value from localStorage or use default
            isLoggedIn: localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn') || 0
        }

        // Listen to storage event
        window.addEventListener('storage', (e) => this.storageChanged(e));

        // Bind this to storageChanged()
        this.storageChanged = this.storageChanged.bind(this);
    }

    storageChanged(e) {
        if(e.key === 'isLoggedIn') {
            this.setState({isLoggedIn: e.newValue})
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <p>{this.state.isLoggedIn}</p>
    }
}
```

That's how I could hook into the `localStorage` changes using class based component.

Comment: You should `addEventListener` on `componentDidMount` and also don't forget to `removeEventListener` on  `componentWillUnmount`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a hook that check for `localStorage` changes like in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#Responding_to_storage_changes_with_the_StorageEvent).

```
useEffect(() => {

    function checkStorage(e){
        if('keyStateYouWantToSync' == e.key && stateYouWantToSync != JSON.parse(e.newValue)){
            setStateYouWantToSync(JSON.parse(e.newValue))
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('storage', checkStorage)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('storage', checkStorage)
})
```

You can also change the `key` checking to what ever `key` you want to check.

## Edit:

For class components

```
checkStorage = (e) => {
    if('keyStateYouWantToSync' == e.key && this.state.stateYouWantToSync != JSON.parse(e.newValue)){
        this.setState({stateYouWantToSync: JSON.parse(e.newValue)})
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener('storage', this.checkStorage)
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    window.removeEventListener('storage', this.checkStorage)
}
```

Comment: Can I use this in my Class based component?

Comment: Thanks @vencovsky, here's latest on this. The`checkStorage` fires when I manually change a value from Inspect > Application > Local Storage. But does not fire when the value is programmatically changed via some other event (ex: `onClick`). I tried removing `e.preventDefault()` from `onClick` handler but no luck. Any idea why?