# useEffect equivalent in a class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm wanting to close a component when clicking off it and have the below code.

How would this useEffect look in a class component?

```
let panelRef = useRef()

useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
    if (!panelRef.current?.contains(event.target)) {
      console.log('hello')
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Possibly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56772703/useeffect-alternate-for-class-component) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) to replace your `useEffect`. Along with it, you didn't clean up your mouse event which may cause unexpected mouse behaviours, although the component was unmounted, so I'd suggest you should use [`componentWillUnmount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount) to clean up your mouse event too.

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  mouseDown(event) {
    if (!panelRef.current?.contains(event.target)) {
      console.log("hello");
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.mouseDown);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.mouseDown);
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>Your JSX</h1>;
  }
}
```